# Setting a Model before saving using devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using devise for my User models in a RoR project.

My User model belongs to a Plan (basic, hobby, professional, etc)

I have a RegistrationController to control the registration of a new user. Like this:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
```

When a new user is created (after checking duplicity, password rules, etc) I want to add to each new user of the app the basic plan (because of businnes rules related to credit card, etc...)

So basic, I want that, for each User created something like:

```
#forget about this hard coding on Plan
@user.plan = Plan.find(1)
```

I dont know witch method I can add this part of my code. Because this is made on devise.

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your devise model is backed by ActiveRecord (most likely), and so you have access to all of the ActiveRecord lifecycle hooks, such as before_save. Open your user model and put in:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  #...
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  #...
  before_save :assign_plan

  def assign_plan
    self.plan = Plan.find_by_name('basic').first
  end
  #...
end
```

Comment: Hey buddy. I did that (and added some debug lines puts) and assign_plan is never called.

Comment: That's odd - there must be something else going on, then. Devise supports these callbacks through ActiveRecord: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/Callbacks . . Is the User being saved properly? before_save only happens if validation passes, so if there was an error in the User, you wouldn't see your print statements because it would never be called. Also make sure you spring stop / spring start just in case its a caching issue not seeing your new code.

Comment: The problem here, is that my user belongs to a plan. I dont know it the validation happens before or later, but, if i check the errors, in the rails console, it says: " @messages={:plan=>["must exist"]}, @details={:plan=>[{:error=>:blank}]}> "

Comment: Ah there you go. So it looks like you have a validates_presence_of :plan on your User model. Since that fails since the assigning of the plan happens AFTER the validation runs, it will never save the user, and the callback will never fire. Remove that validation and try again

Comment: i didnt. Triple checked that :(

Comment: Can you try creating a user in rails console? Try to isolate the problem to just your user model for now, to see if that's whats giving you trouble, or if its some place else like the controller. In console do (something like): User.create(first_name: "test", email: "test@test.com", password: "test", password_confirmation: "test")

Comment: Try changing `before_save` to `before_validation`

Comment: And use `||=` assignment instead of `=` to not override something coming from the browser.

Comment: Hey bkimble. I used it on the console. I did a puts on the "before_save" method, and the method is called. But, when I insert:

Answer (score 0):

You could add the plan in the `before_save` callback on the `User` model instead of handling it in the users controller. Another way is to add the `plan_id` to the devise params as mentioned in https://jacopretorius.net/2014/03/adding-custom-fields-to-your-devise-user-model-in-rails-4.html. This will save the plan directly when the user model is being saved